# Algorithm for Negating Sentences

Tags: nlp, text-processing, linguistics, negation

I was wondering if anyone was familiar with any attempts at algorithmic sentence negation.

For example, given a sentence like "This book is good" provide any number of alternative sentences meaning the opposite like "This book is not good" or even "This book is bad".

Obviously, accomplishing this with a high degree of accuracy would probably be beyond the scope of current NLP, but I'm sure there has been some work on the subject.  If anybody knows of any work, care to point me to some papers?

Comment: just add "... NOT!" to the end of any statement to negate it ;)

Comment: Or in an Orwellian/1984 sense, add the "un" prefix to any adjective... "This book is ungood" :-)

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your usage goals?

Comment: I'm really looking for more of a link to academic papers on the subject, if any exist.

Comment: I think you're going to have tremendous problems with this assignment. You need not only be able to extract the words that can be negated, you also need to identify the carrying part of the sentence. For instance, "John, since he was awake, read his good book". What would the negated part here be? "John, since he wasn't awake, did not read his bad book"?

Answer (score 8):

While I'm not aware of any work that specifically looks at automatically generating negated sentences, I imagine a good place to start would be to read up on linguistics work in [formal semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics) and [pragmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics). A good accessible introduction would be [Steven C. Levinson's Pragmatics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521294142) book.

One issue that I think you'll run into is that it can be very difficult to negate all the information that is conveyed by a sentence. For example, take:

```
John fixed the vase that he broke.
```

Even if you change this to **John did not fix the vase that he broke**, there is a [presupposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presupposition) that there is a vase and that John broke it.

Similarly, simply negating the sentence **John did not stopped using drugs** as **John stopped using drugs** still conveys that John, at one point, used drugs. A more thorough negation would be **John never used drugs**.

Some existing natural language processing (NLP) work that you might want to look at is MacCartney and Manning 2007's [Natural Logic for Textual Inference](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~wcmac/papers/natlog-wtep07.pdf). In this paper they use George Lakoff's notion of Natural Logic and Sanchez Valencia's monotonicity calculus to create software that automatically determines whether one sentence entails another.  You could probably use some their techniques for detecting non-entailment to artificially construct negated and contradicting sentences.

Comment: Perhaps he did not fix the vase that did not exist and that he did not break? And come to think of it, is he a she? Or... Did he really break the vase instead of fixing it, after he fixed it?

Comment: Also, the sentence "John never used drugs", when taken out of context may carry a meaning that someone is trying to hide something. For instance, if a large headline of CNN suddenly said "XYZ never had relations with a goat", it sort of implies that someone have alleged that. Perhaps the most thorough negation would be to rewrite the sentence to something completely different, "John is happy".

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend checking out [wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/). You can use it to lookup antonyms for a word, so you could conceivably replace "bad" with "not good" since bad is an antonym of good. [NLTK](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/toc-nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet-module.html) has a simple python interface to wordnet.

Answer (score 2):

The naïve way of course, is to try to add "not" right after {am,are,is}. I have no idea how this will work in your setting though, it will probably only work with predicate-like sentences.

Comment: The naïve way of course, is not to try to add "not" right after {am,are,is not}

Answer (score 2):

For simple sentences parse looking for adverbs or adjectives given the English grammar rules and substitute an antonym if only one meaning exists. Otherwise use the correct English negation rule to negate the verb (ie: is -> is not).

High level algorithm:

1. Look up each word for it's type (noun, verb, adjective, adverb, conjunction, etc...)
2. Infer sentence structure from word type sequences (Your sentence was: article, noun, verb, adjective/adverb; This is known to be a simple sentence.)
3. For simple sentences, choose one invertible word and invert it. Either by using an antonym, or negating the verb.

For more complex sentences, such as those with subordinate clauses, you will need to have more complex analysis, but for simple sentences, this shouldn't be infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar process for first-order logic.  The usual algorithm is to map `P` to `not P`, and then perform valid translations to move the `not` somewhere convenient, e.g.:

```
Original:    (not R(x) => exists(y) (O(y) and P(x, y)))
Negate it:   not (not R(x) => exists(y) (O(y) and P(x, y)))
Rearrange:   not (R(x) or exists(y) (O(y) and P(x, y)))
             not R(x) and not exists(y) (O(y) and P(x, y))
             not R(x) and forall(y) not (O(y) and P(x, y))
             not R(x) and forall(y) (not O(y) or not P(x, y))
```

Performing the same on English you'd be negating "If it's not raining here, then there is some activity that is an outdoors activity and can be performed here" to "It is NOT the case that ..." and finally into "It's not raining and every possible activity is either not for outdoors or can't be performed here."

Natural language is a lot more complicated than first-order logic, of course...  but if you can parse the sentence into something where the words "not", "and", "or", "exists" etc. can be identified, then you should be able to perform similar translations.

Answer (score 1):

For a **rule-based negation approach**, you can take a look at the **Python module [negate](https://github.com/dmlls/negate)**<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I am the author of the module.</sup>

As for some papers related to the topic, you can take a look at:

- [Understanding by Understanding Not: Modeling Negation in Language Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.03519.pdf)
- [An Analysis of Natural Language Inference Benchmarks through the Lens of Negation](https://aclanthology.org/2020.emnlp-main.732.pdf)
- [Not another Negation Benchmark: The NaN-NLI Test Suite for Sub-clausal Negation](https://aclanthology.org/2022.aacl-main.65/)

Answer (score -1):

Nice demos using NTLK - http://text-processing.com/demo and a short writeup - http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/.

Comment: Negative sentences aren't the same thing as negative sentiments. Here's a positive sentence with a negative sentiment: 'The movie was awful.' Here's a negative sentence with a positive sentiment: 'The movie was not less than the greatest I have ever seen.'

Comment: @Tommy, I disagree with your generalized. "The movie was awful" is a valid NOTing of "The movie was good". i.e. awful is a valid synonym for "not good", just as "bad" is in your post above.